# Custom configuration unrecognized attribute for remove element

Tags: c#, xml, web-config

I have a custom configuration section that is throwing the following error:

```
Unrecognized attribute 'path'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.
```

The rest of the section does not have any problems loading. But once I add a `<remove>` element to the collection in question, the configuration fails to load.

Here's the code for the problematic section:

```
[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(PathElement), CollectionType = ConfigurationElementCollectionType.AddRemoveClearMap)]
public class PathElementCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    public PathElementCollection()
    {
        // Load the default values...
        BaseAdd(new PathElement() { Path = "/content/" });
    }

    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new PathElement();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((PathElement)element).Path;
    }
}

public class PathElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    public const string PathPropertyName = "path";

    [ConfigurationProperty(PathPropertyName, IsRequired = true)]
    public string Path
    {
        get { return (string)this[PathPropertyName]; }
        set { this[PathPropertyName] = value; }
    }
}
```

How I'm loading the section in the module that uses it:

```
CustomSection configSection = (CustomSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection(CustomSection.SectionName);
```

Example configuration:

```
<ignoredPaths>
    <remove path="/content/" />
    <add path="/test/" />
</ignoredPaths>
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like this is only occuring on `<remove>` elements. Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your classes should look like this

```
    [XmlRoot("ignoredPaths")]
    public class IgnoredPaths
    {
        PathElementCollection paths {get;set;}
    }
    [XmlInclude(typeof(Remove))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(Add))]
    public class PathElementCollection
    {
        [XmlAttribute("path")]
        public string path {get;set;}
    }
    [XmlRoot("remove")]
    public class Remove : PathElementCollection
    {
    }
    [XmlRoot("add")]
    public class Add : PathElementCollection
    {
    }​
```